# NullPointerException при старте приложения

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="ru.dalavstudio.matfor9.Stepeni_i_korni"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_stepeni_i_korni"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:fillViewport="false"
    android:background="@color/background">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Степени"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/textView" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/svoystva_stepeni"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Activity:

```
FloatingActionButton fab;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_stepeni_i_korni);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.fab:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: При запуске на эмуляторе приложение останавливается.

Comment: Лог ошибки дайте.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Метки (теги) нужны для того, чтобы выделить основные моменты ВОПРОСА, по которым другие пользователи быстрее смогут найти решение аналогичной проблемы, а не для демонстрации собственных предпочтений в выборе IDE. Вопрос никак не связан с проблемами при работе IDE Android Studio и этот тег в вопросе не нужен.

Answer (score 3):

Мой магический шар говорит что у вас `NPE` на строке

> fab.setOnClickListener(this);

Т.к. у вас в разметке нема `FAB` и, засим, `fab=null`.

Ваша проблема может быть решена или добавлением `FAB` в разметку или убиранием этой строки из кода.